# Specific exchange user under one database not able to login to the OWA

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, outlook-web-app

Specific exchange users under one database are not able to login to the OWA. But when a user moves to another database its working. Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the error information when you cannot access OWA? Or are there any errors in the event log?
2. What is your version of Exchange?

Comment: Showing this...

Sorry, we can't get that information right now. Please try again later. If the problem continues, contact your helpdesk.
X-ClientId: JNOP - UHJA - JGJF - LUA
X-FEServer: A0410PEXMBX01
Date: 12/25/2022 6:25:37 AM

Comment: Exchange version 2013

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Can the user login to the EAC?
Have you performed a migration? Check that the mailbox still has a move request, and if so, remove it.
Reference Articles: https://superuser.com/questions/915659/exchange-2013-eac-owa-error-we-cant-get-that-information-right-now

If the user is still unable to login to OWA, then it is possible that under that database, the user's mailbox is corrupted for various reasons, in which case moving it to another database can solve this problem.